# How to set an index on a table which requiers separate queries on each column?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a question about indexing in MySQL. I apologize in advance if this specific question has been answered which I don't believe it has.

I have a table with 28 columns and a primary key. I must update the table with small amounts of data, anywhere from 1-1000 records at a time and nothing more. Each column with the exception of Date is a Float and I must perform 28 queries that have a where clause that creates a bounds for the value to look up (being a float). The table itself is 5.5million rows.

How do I go about indexing this kind of table/query combination?

Comment: What kind of information is stored in the majority of the columns?

Comment: I've figured it out; splitting the table seems to be about 8X faster with indexes

Comment: Partitioning might be a better option